# Java / mvn code coverage AND redundancy?

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, code-coverage

Have a monolthic app that runs JUnit tests through Surefire and Maven.  I see several options out there that will tell me about code coverage, but I'm trying to find something a little different:

Specifically, I'd like to run a mvn build that generates a report (or use an Eclipse plugin that does the same) that will give me a way to see what tests are all pretty much doing the same thing, **in addition** to the parts of the app that do not have good coverage.  Does something like this exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To combine with @alexbt answer you can utilize the report you have with Jacoco but plug that report into SonarQube (you can easily install it locally) then get the [SonarLint](http://www.sonarlint.org/eclipse/index.html) Eclipse plugin that connects to the local SonarQube instance to get the integration you want.

In addition you get copy and paste detection and *some* redundant code checks.  I say *some* because `public` methods are never marked as redundant.

Here are an examples of an online report with and without major problems

- https://sonarcloud.io/dashboard?id=org.apache.maven:maven
- https://sonarqube.com/dashboard?id=net.trajano.mojo:batik-maven-plugin
- https://sonarcloud.io/component_measures/domain/Coverage?id=net.trajano.jetng:jetng

One bonus is you can centralize the rules for your team.

Answer (score 2):

I doesn't cover the *redundancy* part, but for the coverage you may use [Jacoco](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/maven.html), it's easy to setup with maven:

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.7.201606060606</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>

<reporting>
    <excludeDefaults>true</excludeDefaults>
    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/site</outputDirectory>
    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

To generate the report, type `mvn site`. The reports will be created under `target/site`.